# Show UITextField above Keyboard

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, uitextfield

I am using the following tutorial to show the uitextfield above the keyboard at all times:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-keeping-content-from-underneath-the-keyboard/

But the problem is the uitextfield only gets shown above the keyboard if the person starts typing into the field, but not if the cursor is in the textfield.

How can I change it so that the uitextfield gets shown above the keyboard once the cursor is in the UITextField?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check `UITextFieldDelegate` and select appropriate method.

In this tutorial they use `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method to assign active textfield.
As it clear from method name, it executes when someone start typing in text field.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the sample code and work just fine for me. The only thing that I figured you could misunderstood is in the case the keyboard it's already below the textField, in these cases the view will not scroll.

I hope this helps. If it's not this that you want, please tell me more about it.

Comment: Yes it does not scroll up if the text field is already below the keyboard. You have to start typing into the text field for it to scroll up. So if the text field is below the keyboard and you put your cursor there, the text field stays below the keyboard, but once you keep typing, it moves up. I want it so that it moves up once you put your cursor there.

Comment: Sorry, as I said before, in the example it works just the way you want. Do you builded a project for yourself or do you testing that example?